Why it always returns only 10 rows of result even if collection.num_entities>1000 and limit=10
Why it always returns only 10 rows of result even if collection.num_entities>1000 and limit=10
The script is as belowed:
collection = Collection(name="test_collection")

collection.load()
print(collection.num_entities)
search_params = {
"metric_type": "IP",
"params": {"nprobe": 10}
}

np_query_embeddings = np.array(query_embeddings, dtype=np.float32)
norms = np.linalg.norm([np_query_embeddings], axis=1, keepdims=True)
normalized_query_embeddings = np_query_embeddings / norms

query_vectors = normalized_query_embeddings.tolist()
limit = 1000

results = collection.search(
data=query_vectors,
anns_field="embedding",
param=search_params,
limit=limit,
consistency_level="Strong",
)
print(results)

Display:
8503 ["['id: 449617239426872838, distance: 0.7159370183944702, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426877164, distance: 0.7090992331504822, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426880450, distance: 0.699631929397583, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426876554, distance: 0.6782248020172119, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426876178, distance: 0.6769057512283325, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426880350, distance: 0.6754627823829651, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426875291, distance: 0.6698116064071655, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426877126, distance: 0.6647711396217346, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426876516, distance: 0.6610612869262695, entity: {}', 'id: 449617239426880437, distance: 0.6571118831634521, entity: {}']"]

print() will print limited results(default to 10) to reduce printed message size, especially if you search back embeddings.
Please get all results by res.hits, res.ids or res.distances
Ref: https://milvus.io/api-reference/pymilvus/v2.4.x/ORM/Collection/search.md

If you refer to the Milvus Documentation linked here: https://milvus.io/api-reference/pymilvus/v2.2.x/Collection/search().md
We see that the search() method returns a SearchResult object, and print(results) in fact calls the str() method of the SearchResult class, which only prints at most 10 query results as shown below in both the link and the code snippet: https://github.com/milvus-io/pymilvus/blob/e95f5a5294ff28588c14a2f3f5aae19d9210a47e/pymilvus/client/abstract.py#L515
def __str__(self) -> str:
    """Only print at most 10 query results"""
    return f"data: {list(map(str, self[:10]))} {'...' if len(self) > 10 else ''}, cost: {self.cost}"

To print all search results, you can try implementing the following code:
for i, result in enumerate(results):
    print("Search result for vector #{}: ".format(i))
    for j, res in enumerate(result):
        print("  Rank {}: {}".format(j, res))

